# What is a "saint" in Islam?

Tags: terminology

How does Islam define the word *saint*? Does it just mean any reasonably good person; or a person in close communication with God? Is it in some way analogous to the Christian concept of a "saved" person? Can you call someone a saint while they're still alive, or is that title given only to a person now dead?

*Britannica* has [a short paragraph on saints in Islam](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/516666/saint/34118/Islam) which, if I'm reading it correctly, says that saints are not an "official" part of the religion. Perhaps. I'm not actually sure what it's saying. I do note that the word *saint* is used three times on this site, without any definition being given, so presumably there is a fairly standard accepted definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of *saint* is not universal in Islam, and as far as I know is almost exclusive to Sufist Islam.

In Sufism, a "wali" (saint) is a particularly pious person chosen by Allah Himself. They rank above most people but below prophets. Some of them are granted a *karama* (minor miracle) or more, but they are not infallible.

For example, Maryam (Mary) in Sufism is regarded as a *wali*.

Comment: In fact, it is not just the Sufis who believe in saints. Both Sunnis and Shiites do with the exception of Salafis/Wahhabis.

Answer (score 6):

A saint or Wali in Islam refers to a friend of Allah, Allah has said in the Quran that his friends, Awliya' will have nor fear nor shall they grieve.

> أَلَآ إِنَّ أَوۡلِيَآءَ ٱللَّهِ لَا خَوۡفٌ عَلَيۡهِمۡ وَلَا هُمۡ
>   يَحۡزَنُونَ (٦٢)
>
> Behold! verily on the friends of Allah there is no fear, nor shall
>   they grieve; (62)

Read:   [1](http://www.allaahuakbar.net/misconceptions/121.htm)

Comment: Interesting, I never thought of it that way!